# SQL Beginner - SQLite vs INTERVAL

Tags: python, sqlite

I tried all kinds of things, rewriting the section, changing the line, etc.

As well searching I couldn't find anything like it. I'm pretty sure that is the way I'm trying to use a `variable` for the `datestamp value`.

Sorry I know it's just a syntax error but I can't solve it. I started SQL just a week ago and this stuck me for 2 days now.

What I'm trying to do in that line is to search in my `db` which `lines` have been at the same time or interval of 1 hour as the person searched.

Syntax error line (68):

```
 c.execute('''SELECT COUNT (*)
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?, interval 1 hour''', (z,))
```

full code:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect('covid.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def enter_data():
    def create_table():
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        covidTrack(
        name TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        ph_number INTEGER,
        datestamp TEXT,
        keyword TEXT)''')


    i_name = input('Please insert FULL NAME : \n ...')
    i_email = input('Please insert EMAIL : \n ...')
    i_number = input('Please insert PHONE NUMBER : \n ...')

    print('Your data has been saved for acelerated contact, thank you.')

    time.sleep(3)


    def data_entry():
        date, keyword = dynamic_data_entry()
        c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (i_name, i_email, i_number, date, keyword))
        conn.commit()


    def dynamic_data_entry():
        keyword = 'nameofvenue'
        date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%p'))
        return date, keyword
        conn.commit()

    def read_from_db():
        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack''')
        conn.commit()

    create_table()
    data_entry()
    read_from_db()

def data_search():
    x = input('''Select desired search: \n
    Search by FULL NAME. \n
    Search by DATE AND TIME \n
    Search by phone number \n
    ~ ~ ~''')

    if x.lower() == 'full name':
         specify_name = input('Please insert full name. \n ')
         select_query = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack WHERE NAME ==(?) ''', (specify_name,))
         information = c.fetchall()
         for row in information:
             print('\nName:', row[0])
             print('Email:', row[1])
             print('Phone Number:', row[2])
             print('Date and Time:', row[3])
             print('Venue:', row[4])
             print('\n')
             z = row[3]

             c.execute('''SELECT COUNT (*)
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ?, interval 1 hour''', (z,))

             general_information = c.fetchall()
             print('Matching Results: \n ')
             for rows in general_information:
                 print(rows[0:4])

    if x.lower() == 'date and time':
        print('Not finished.')

    if x.lower() == 'phone number':
        print('not finished.')

choose_funtion = input('''Please choose action: \n
A TO ENTER DATA. \n
B TO SEARCH DATA. \n ''')

if choose_funtion.lower() == 'a':
    print('You choose enter data.')
    enter_data()
if choose_funtion.lower() == 'b':
    print('You choose search data.')
    data_search()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by the `,` after `WHERE datestamp >= ?`, but even if you remove it you will still get an error because SQLite does not support `interval` values.

The correct syntax is:

```
WHERE datestamp >= ? AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')
```

which is also likely to use an index on the column `datestamp`.

So your code should be:

```
c.execute('''SELECT COUNT (*)
             FROM covidTrack
             WHERE datestamp >= ? AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')''', (z, z))
```

But, you should know that SQLite functions like `datetime()` work only with timestamps in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.
So you should use this format for the values you store in `datestamp` and for the parameter `z` that you pass to the `?` placeholder:

```
date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Also, if you want `datestamp` to store the current timestamp, it would be easier to define a default value for it in the `CREATE` statement of the table:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
covidTrack(
name TEXT,
email TEXT,
ph_number INTEGER,
datestamp TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
keyword TEXT)''')
```

This way you don't need to pass any value for `datestamp` when you insert a new row.

Comment: 1- Thank you very much, that line works fine without traceback, but is not really giving me any result. I'm looking for the `SELECT` to look for all the `data` saved `from` the `entry` of the `data` of the search till `one hour after`. Result: `Matching Results:

(0,)` 

2- I'm not quite sure what are you doing by creating a default value. If you could foward a explanation would be great. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero maybe you don't get any results because you store the values in the wrong format. Store timestamps only in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. This is the only valid text format for SQLite. I proposed a default value because it seems (from your code) that you want the column `datestamp` to store the timestamp of the insertion of the row. Also do you want the rows that have datestamp starting from `?` till `+1 hour`? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: Perfect, sorry about that I didn't change the timestamp format. What I'm looking for is if I enter a row at 15:20 and then I look for that row I want it to show all the rows entered from 15:20 to 16:20 and print certain columns like NAME, EMAIL AND PHONE. But is more difficult that what I thought.

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero then the condition should be: `WHERE datestamp >= ? AND datestamp <= datetime(?, '+1 hours')`. I edited my code. Also `z` should be in the same format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much! Now I'm getting just one result and is the row that I searched for but I suppose it's a problem with my print line. ` general_information = c.fetchall()
             print('Matching Results: \n ')
             for rows in general_information:
                 print(row) ` . Again thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sqlite supports `interval`. You can use something like:

```
 WHERE ? BETWEEN datetime(datestamp,'-1 hours') AND datetime(datestamp,'+1 hours')
```

Comment: Keeps on giving the same TraceBack, I didn't know SQLite wouldn't support that. Thank you I will research more in deep.